# Why setContentView doesn't disappear when changing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a navigation drawer and when I click on one of the menus, I want the default content to disappear, but it just doesn't happen and when I click on a new menu it's still there.
This is really annoying, I've been trying to find solution the whole day and I'm going crazy now.

Please help me out, if you can. Thanks in advance!

I copy the whole code here. (p.s.: this is the first and last time I'm programming on Android, this is a nightmare...I just must do this now :/)

```
public class About extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private NavigationView navigationView;
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

ImageButton FAB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    FAB = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    FAB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(About.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            //FAB click, call other thing...

        }
    });

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new ListViewFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    setNavDrawer();
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_gallery);
}
    private void setNavDrawer() {
    // Initializing Toolbar and setting it as the actionbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //Initializing NavigationView

    //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


            //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.nav_camera:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ContentFragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction f = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    f.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
                    f.commit();
                    return true;

                // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                case R.id.nav_gallery:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Whatever", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    UserFragment fragment2 = new UserFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction f2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    f2.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2);
                    f2.commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_slideshow:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SOON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_share:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SOON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SOON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

            }
        }
    });


    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close){

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank

            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is necessay or else your hamburger icon wont show up
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.about, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  } 
}
```

Comment: you need to add a backgroundcolor to your listviewfragment.xml

Comment: Have you tried `drawerLayout.closeDrawer(navigationView);` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use these code on menu click..

```
Fragment fragment = new ContentFragment();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.remove(new CurrentFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

an also add these lines in xml

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
fragment = new ContentFragment ();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
               .commit();
```